# how to find search technique for evolutionary computing through agent technology?

Tags: evolutionary-algorithm, multi-agent, agent-based-modeling

I am trying to find new search technique for evolutionary computing through Agent technology. I do not have any idea about this and want to implement it. anybody familiar with this? Can anyone suggest me some research papers for me? I searched on Google. bit I could not find any interesting papers. plz help me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, read this wikipedia article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolutionary_computation
and then you can go deeper wiht the multi-agent thing: http://age.iisg.agh.edu.pl/emas/intro.html

here is a paper

[Evolutionary multi-agent systems: An adaptive and dynamic approach to optimization](http://www.andrew.cmu.edu/org/IDIG/Evolutionary%20Multi-Agent%20Systems%20-%20An%20Adaptive%20and%20Dynamic%20Approach%20to%20Optimization.pdf)
 from cmu.eduL Hanna… - Journal of Mechanical Design, 2009 - link.aip.org
This paper explores the ability of a virtual team of specialized strategic software agents to 
cooperate and evolve to adaptively search an optimization design space. Our goal is to 
demonstrate and understand how such dynamically evolving teams may search more ...
Cited by 5

Check who cited it, then you have more:
http://scholar.google.com/scholar?cites=13074976072769467020&as_sdt=2005&sciodt=0,5&hl=en

[Search Strategies in Evolutionary Multi-Agent Systems: The Effect of Cooperation and Reward on Solution Quality](http://link.aip.org/link/?JMDEDB/133/061005/1)
LH Landry… - Journal of Mechanical Design, 2011 - link.aip.org
Cooperation and reward of strategic agents in an evolutionary optimization framework is 
explored in order to better solve engineering design problems. Agents in this Evolutionary 
Multi-Agent Systems (EMAS) framework rely on one another to better their performance, ...
Related articles